# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')

Tags: javascript, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am experiencing the following error in my code: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend'). This error is occurring when I am trying to access the ‘backend’ property of an object, but it is returning as undefined. I have checked my code multiple times and cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')
    at Engine.moveData (engine.ts:426:1)
    at DataStorage.get (backend.ts:55:1)
    at MathBackendCPU.incRef (backend_cpu.ts:106:1)
    at Object.reshape [as kernelFunc] (Reshape.ts:40:1)
    at kernelFunc (engine.ts:646:1)
    at engine.ts:712:1
    at Engine.scopedRun (engine.ts:480:1)
    at Engine.runKernelFunc (engine.ts:708:1)
    at Engine.runKernel (engine.ts:553:1)
    at reshape_ (reshape.ts:60:1)
```

Dependencies:

```
 "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.1.0",
 "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^4.1.0",
 "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^4.1.0",
 "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.7.4",
```

If anyone has experienced this error or has any suggestions on how to fix it, please let me know.

Comment: If you Google it there's a bunch of Github threads and SO posts about this exact error message with regards to tensor flow (TF), with causes such as mismatch between TF JS version and the converter TF version, and many others reasons. Have you looked through all those? What have you tried

Comment: I have checked the github issues also, but have not been able to find a solution. Therefore, I am posting my question on StackOverflow in hopes of receiving assistance.

Comment: People are encountering issues with updating tfjs node to the latest version. I have also checked on GitHub and other platforms, but haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

`@tensorflow/tfjs-node` is a bundle package of `tjfs-core`, `tfjs-converter` and others.
`@tensorflow/tfjs` is also a bundle package, but for browsers.

so you have dependency on TWO different bundles - of which there could be only one. and then you have MAJOR version incompatibility: v4 vs v1.

and on top of that you have individual packages like `tfjs-core` and `tfjs-converter`. really, this has no chance of working.

Comment: do you know by chance where could I find documentation about the main relationships between packages?